# Why is sum slower than foldl' in haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci, fold

How come the default `sum` in ghc is ~10 times slower than its `foldl'` (the [stricter equivalent](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl') of `foldl`) equivalent? And if that's the case, why isn't it implemented using `foldl'`?

```
import Data.List
> foldl' (+) 0 [1..10^7]
50000005000000
(0.39 secs, 963,528,816 bytes)

> sum [1..10^7]
50000005000000
(4.13 secs, 1,695,569,176 bytes)
```

For completeness here are also the stats of `foldl` and `foldr`.

```
> foldl (+) 0 [1..10^7]
50000005000000
(4.02 secs, 1,695,828,752 bytes)

> foldr (+) 0 [1..10^7]
50000005000000
(3.78 secs, 1,698,386,648 bytes)
```

Looks like `sum` is implemented using `foldl` since their runtime is similar. Tested on ghc 7.10.2.

Comment: They're the same if you compile with -O2.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner sorry

Comment: See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2agxcb/why_is_sum_lazy/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `sum` function is implemented using `foldl` in GHC:

```
-- | The 'sum' function computes the sum of a finite list of numbers.
sum                     :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
{-# INLINE sum #-}
sum                     =  foldl (+) 0
```

as can be seen [in the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#sum).

It has to be this way, because it is the specification [in the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/report/node/2010/haskellch9.html#dx16-172048).

The rationale was likely that for certain lazy element types of the list, `foldl` is the right thing to do. (I personally think that `foldl` is almost always wrong and only `foldl'` should be used.)

With sufficient optimization, GHC will inline that definition, specialize it to the element type at hand, notice that the loop is strict, and force the evaluation of the accumulator in every iteration; effectively turning this into a `foldl'`, as observed by @AndrásKovács.

Since GHC-7.10, [`sum` itself](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#sum) is a method of the `Foldable` type class, and the default definition goes via `foldMap`. The `instance Foldable []` however overrides this with the above definition of `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement @Joachim Breitner's answer, I found this [blog post](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/90/), a very interesting read (taken from the reddit discussion, thanks to @ZhekaKozlov for the link).

> When Haskell 1.0 was published on this day 24 years ago there was no seq function at all, so there was no choice but to define foldl in the “classic” way.
>
> Eventually, six years later after much discussion, we got the seq function in Haskell 1.3. Though actually in Haskell 1.3 seq was part of an Eval class, so you couldn’t use it just anywhere, such as in foldl. In Haskell 1.3 you would have had to define foldl' with the type:

```
foldl' :: Eval b => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

> Haskell 1.4 and Haskell 98 got rid of the Eval class constraint for seq but foldl was not changed. Hugs and GHC and other implementations added the non-standard foldl'.
>
> I suspect that people then considered it a compatibility and inertia issue. It was easy enough to add a non-standard foldl' but you can’t so easily change the standard.
>
> I suspect that if we had had seq from the beginning then we would have defined foldl using it.
>
> Miranda, one of Haskell’s predecessor languages, already had seq 5 years before Haskell 1.0.

BTW, I've managed to shave 20 ms more by using

```
foldl1' (+) [1..10^7]
```

So, I guess `foldl1'` should be the default for `sum` and `product` (with special handling of empty lists).